# Records get inserted into database every time I run the program. SQLitedatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

```
//Here is the code for Content provider. It has two uri's //1)content://authority/student(table name) and //2)content://authority/student/_id to identify each student.


public class StudentProvider extends ContentProvider {
    public static final int  STUDENT=0;
    public static final int  STUDENT_ID=1;
    private static HashMap<String, String> STUDENTS_PROJECTION_MAP;
    public  StudentHelper helper;
    UriMatcher match=buildUrimatcher();
    static UriMatcher buildUrimatcher()
    {
        UriMatcher matcher=new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        matcher.addURI(StudentContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY,StudentContract.PATH,STUDENT);
        matcher.addURI(StudentContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY,StudentContract.PATH+"/#",STUDENT_ID);
        return matcher;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {

      helper=new StudentHelper(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] strings, String s, String[] strings2, String s2) {

       SQLiteDatabase database=helper.getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder builder=new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        builder.setTables(StudentContract.Student.Table);
        int id=match.match(uri);
        switch (id)
        {

            case STUDENT:
            {
                builder.setProjectionMap(STUDENTS_PROJECTION_MAP);
                break;
            }
            case STUDENT_ID:
            {
                builder.appendWhere(StudentContract.Student._ID+"="+uri.getPathSegments().get(1));
                break;
            }
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
        }
        Cursor cursor=builder.query(database,strings,s,strings2,null,null,s2);
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(),uri);
        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public int bulkInsert(Uri uri, ContentValues[] values) {
        SQLiteDatabase database=helper.getWritableDatabase();
        int id=match.match(uri);
        switch (id)
        {
            case STUDENT:
            {
                database.beginTransaction();
                int count=0;
                try
                {
                    for(ContentValues value:values)
                    {
                       long rid= database.insert(StudentContract.Student.Table,null,value);
                        if(rid!=-1)
                        {
                            count++;
                            Log.d("Bulk insert","success");
                        }
                    }
                    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
                }finally {
                    database.endTransaction();
                }
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
                return count;
            }
            default:return super.bulkInsert(uri, values);
        }


    }


}

//Here is the code of Activity which inserts records into database  from an //array. Im inserting records into database using bulk insert method.
```

// code for inserting records into database.

```
 final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            String[] names=new String[]{"sai","kiran","seenu","akhil","devi","sanath","patro","patch","reddy","sai kiran"};
            ListView listView= (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Cursor cursor= (Cursor) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                   Uri Student= ContentUris.withAppendedId(StudentContract.Student.CONTENT_URI,cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(StudentContract.Student._ID)));
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),Student.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Cursor c=getActivity().getContentResolver().query(StudentContract.Student.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
            cursorAdapter =new TodoCursorAdapter(getActivity(),c,0);

            String[] grades=new String[]{"A","A1","B","C","A1","C","D","D","B","A"};
            Vector<ContentValues> valuesVector=new Vector<ContentValues>(names.length);
           for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
           {
               ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
               values.put(StudentContract.Student.name,names[i]);
               values.put(StudentContract.Student.grade,grades[i]);
               valuesVector.add(values);
           }
            if(valuesVector.size()>0)
            {
                ContentValues[] valueses=new ContentValues[valuesVector.size()];
                valuesVector.toArray(valueses);
                getActivity().getContentResolver().bulkInsert(StudentContract.Student.CONTENT_URI,valueses);

            }


           listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

Every time i execute the program, 10 records are inserted again into database. I dont want records to be inserted every time the program is executed. Im beginner in this field any help is appreciated.
StudentHelper class extends Sqliteopenhelper and it contains oncreate() and onupgrade()  methods

Answer (score 0):

Why is this there ?

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(StudentContract.Student.name,names[i]);
    values.put(StudentContract.Student.grade,grades[i]);
    valuesVector.add(values);
}
```